# MVC Application Fileresult get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, async-await

I am trying to get a pdf from a get request but it fails. When i check console in chrome i get GET http://localhost:50673/Logbook/PrintPage?bilder=checked net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Some IIS issuse? I run this directly in visual studio 2013.

I have tried this code,

```
    [AsyncTimeout(150)]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<FileResult> PrintPage(bool bilder = false)
    {
        --------
     --------
      --------
      --------
    System.IO.FileInfo file =         AsposePDFBuilder.PdfBuilder.ExportForPrint(exportData, hidePronAoInfo, true);

        //System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        //response.ClearContent();
        //response.Clear();
        //response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
        //response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        //response.End();
        ViewBag.Result = "Export är nedladdad";

        return File(file.FullName, "application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, got a jquery loadevent that fired on actionlink class. Got an annoying alert in firefox, chrome did not alert me. Try diffrent browsers is my suggestion.